# How to remove keywords of javascript mode in monaco editor

Tags: monaco-editor

In project that i trying to build i used an editor code.
i try to use the monaco editor.

The main things that i want the editor will support is:

1. mark my custom language keywords, functions etc...
2. intellisense for my custom language.
3. preview functions parameters.

So up now:

- I looked carefully on the monaco editor examples in the official website.
- The results is very close for what i looked for but the **main problem** for me is that although i add the noLib options to my code there is additional keywords, see image below.
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYYu1.jpg
- The other things works. see image https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0EZo.jpg
- I know because i used the javascript/typescript language mode, the marking is problematic.

This is the code that i wrote:

```js
require.config({paths: {'vs': 'lib/package/min/vs'}});

require(['vs/editor/editor.main'], function() {
    let editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('editor'), {
        language: 'typescript',
        minimap: {enabled: false},
    });
    monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.addExtraLib([
        'declare function Foo(a: number,b: number, name: string (optional)) :void',
        'const someString: string ',
    ].join('\n'));

    monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.setCompilerOptions({
        noLib: true,
        allowNonTsExtensions: true,
    });

    editor.updateOptions({fontSize: 20});
});
```

My questions is:

1. There is a way to disable the javascript/typescript additionals keywords so the user can see just my custom language?
2. There is a way to use custom language like in the monaco editor examples and to add the functions preview, like in the picture that i show above?
   (without using the js/ts languages).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same need, don't want javascript/typescript keywords in auto-completion. I solved it using:

```
monaco.editor.create(<your container DOM element here>, {
    . . . .
    suggest: {
        showKeywords: false,
    }
});
```

An older answer I found here: https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/1411, but the API seems to have changed since then.